# Decode html before showing it in AlertDialog Android

Tags: android

I want to decode text before showing it to `AlertDialog`. So I used `Html.fromHtml(String)`, but It is not working my case. I have also tried `escapeHtml()` but still no result.

**My String is :**

```
&lt;div&gt;   The pampiniform plexus is a network of many small veins found in the human male spermatic cord. It is formed by the union of multiple spermatic veins from the back of the testis and tributaries from the epididymis.&lt;br /&gt;   &lt;br /&gt;   &amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;  &lt;div&gt;   The veins of the plexus ascend along the cord in front of the ductus deferens. Below the superficial inguinal ring they unite to form three or four veins, which pass along the inguinal canal, and, entering the abdomen through the deep inguinal ring, coalesce to form two veins. These again unite to form a single vein, the testicular vein, which opens on the right side into the inferior vena cava, at an acute angle, and on the left side into the left renal vein, at a right angle.The pampiniform plexus forms the chief mass of the cord.&lt;br /&gt;   &lt;br /&gt;   &amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;  &lt;div&gt;   In addition to its function in venous return from the testes, the pampiniform plexus also plays a role in the temperature regulation of the testes. It acts as a heat exchanger, cooling blood in adjacent arteries. An abnormal enlargement of the pampiniform plexus is a medical condition called varicocele.&lt;/div&gt;  <br>
```

**My Code :**

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(lstDescription.get(position)).toString());

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RandomQuestion.this).create();

            alertDialog.setView(tv);
            alertDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
```

How to show it as Html Text ???

Comment: what happen write now ? got error or does not decoded ?

Comment: No error, but it is saying string as it is.

Comment: div is not converting ... may be that is reason for that

Answer (score 0):

to decode Html String you can use Html.fromHtml()

like

```
Html.fromHtml((String) htmlCode).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

ok then try this way :

```
String str = lstDescription.get(position)).toString().replace("&lt;","<").replace("&gt;",">").replace("nbsp;", " ");
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(str );
```

Comment: but I have that string in main database and I am gonna to use that one so.

Comment: come on dude. It can contain any html encode code. So Its not possible to replace everything.